# How to deal with old pip requirement in Django South migrations?

Tags: django, django-south

I have an app which is managed with South for quite a while. At one point of the development, I added a custom field to a model that had a pip requirement (sorl-thumbnail), but I removed this requirement later. My problem is that when I try to migrate this app in a fresh new database, South shouts:

```
./manage.py migrate my_app
...
ValueError: Cannot import the required field 'sorl.thumbnail.fields.ImageField'
```

How am I suppose to deal with this old requirement?

Comment: You could fix the migration?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a dirty solution but if you really want to get rid of your sorl-thumbnail dependency you don't have much choice :

Locate the migration file in which the field was added and replace `sorl.thumbnail.fields.ImageField` by something like `django.db.models.fields.files.ImageField`

It should work unless you have [DataMigrations](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations) depending on special features of sorl-thumbnail.