# pybbm error with URLS.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I just got this error after installing `pybbm` and running the server

```
File "/Users/nathann/code/ipals/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybb/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
ImportError: No module named defaults
```

And I am not sure what to do with it since it is apart of `pybb`, and not my code.

This is my `pip freeze`:

```
Django==1.6.3
Markdown==2.4
Pillow==2.4.0
South==0.8.4
bbcode==1.0.16
behave==1.2.4
django-annoying==0.8.0
django-common==0.1.51
django-rosetta==0.7.4
enum34==1.0
parse==1.6.4
parse-type==0.3.4
polib==1.0.4
pybb==0.1.10
pytils==0.3
requests==2.2.1
six==1.6.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using Django 1.6.3. According to [Django 1.4 changelog](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#django-conf-urls-defaults):

> Until Django 1.3, the functions include(), patterns() and url() plus
>   handler404, handler500 were located in a django.conf.urls.defaults
>   module.
>
> In Django 1.4, they live in django.conf.urls.

In other words, you need to upgrade `pybbm` to the latest version:

```
pip install --upgrade pybbm
```

Comment: Should i just not use py bb with Django 1.6.3 ? I keep run ng intp errors. What would you recommend?

Comment: @broinjc the problem is that you are using an old `pybbm`, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to remove migrations for pybbm? I can't seem to get it's tables made...

Comment: I am getting this same error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721021/how-to-deal-with-old-pip-requirement-in-django-south-migrations

Comment: @broinjc haven't ever used `pybbm` personally, but try `pip install sorl-thumbnail`.

Comment: Where are the pybm versions? I use 0.15.6, Django 1.6 and get the "No module named defaults" error on Openshift. I installed pybbm on Openshift using "setup.py".

Comment: AFter "pip install --upgrade pybbm" on Openshift per ssh, it says "req already up-to date"(pybbm 0.15.6)